# move semantics/behaviors in std::bind and std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, move-semantics, stdthread

Please look at the following simple test program, you can just copy and test. I tried with `gcc 4.9` it compiles fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
  Test(const Test &t) { this->name = t.name; std::cout << name << ": copy constructor" << std::endl; }
  Test(Test &&t) {this->name = std::move(t.name); std::cout << name << ": move contructor" << std::endl; }
  Test(const std::string &name) {this->name=name;}

  Test &operator=(const Test &t) {  this->name = t.name; std::cout << name << ": copy operator = " << std::endl; return  *this; }
  Test &operator=(Test &&t) { this->name = std::move(t.name); std::cout << name << ": move operator = " << std::endl; return *this; }

  std::string name;
};


class A
{
public:
  void f(Test t1, Test t2)
  {
    std::cout << "running f" << std::endl;
  }
  void run()
  {
    std::cout << "running run" << std::endl;
    Test t1("t1");
    Test t2("t2");
    auto functor = std::bind(&A::f, this, t1, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::cout << "functor created by bind, t1 is passed into functor" << std::endl;

    std::thread t(functor, t2);

    std::cout << "thread created, functor and t2 passed into thread" << std::endl;
    t.join();
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.run();

  return 0;
}
```

The program gives the following output for gcc 4.9 (mingw)

> running run
>
> t1: copy constructor
>
> functor created by bind, t1 is passed into functor
>
> t2: copy constructor
>
> t1: copy constructor
>
> **t2: move contructor**
>
> **t1: move contructor**
>
> thread created, functor and t2 passed into thread
>
> **t2: move contructor**
>
> **t1: copy constructor**
>
> running f

Please note the bold.

(1) I am curious why there is a **t2 move** and a **t1 move** before the `functor` and the `t2` are passed into the thread?

(2) And why there is a **t2 MOVE** and **t1 COPY** before calling `f()`?

Does gcc's library implementation make some optimization to turn COPY into MOVE for efficiency? For example, before calling `f`, `t2` is MOVED into the `f(Test t1, Test t2)`?

If I changed the above two lines into,

```
auto functor = std::bind(&A::f, this, std::move(t1), std::placeholders::_1);
std::thread t(std::move(functor), std::move(t2));
```

Then everything becomes move, EXCEPT the last "t1 copy".

(3) Why `t1` is still copied ? This is related to (2).

If I change one more line,

```
void f(Test &t1, Test &t2)
```

Then it failed to compile.

(4) Isn't `std::bind` & `std::thread`'s internal implementation store objects `t1` & `t2` which are lvalue? Why call Test & will fail? I am curious what standard says.

If I change it to,

```
void f(const Test &t1, const Test &t2)
```

Everything works fine, and the last two `t2` move and `t1` copy are eliminated.

(5) I just want someone to confirm with me whether this is valid and there's no danger of dangling reference, even IF we store the thread `t` somewhere else. For example, is the following still valid?

```
class A
{
public:
  void f(const Test &t1, const Test &t2)
  {
    std::cout << "running f" << std::endl;
  }
  void run()
  {
    std::cout << "running run" << std::endl;
    Test t1("t1");
    Test t2("t2");
    auto functor = std::bind(&A::f, this, std::move(t1), std::placeholders::_1);
    std::cout << "functor created by bind, t1 is passed into functor" << std::endl;

    std::thread t(std::move(functor), std::move(t2));
    std::cout << "thread created, functor and t2 passed into thread" << std::endl;

    t_internal.swap(t);
  }

  std::thread t_internal;
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.run();
  a.t_internal.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `bind` passes bound arguments as lvalues and perfectly forward anything passed to its `operator()`. `std::thread` passes everything as rvalues. The net result is that the first argument of `f` needs to be copied, while the second argument is moved.

Comment: @T.C., thanks. It is clear to me now. I thought that bind & thread had same behaviour. I didn't know they are different when when invoing the calls. Can you help me look at question (5). I just updated it. I believe it's valid but just need someone to confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) I am curious why there is a t2 move and a t1 move before the functor and the t2 are passed into the thread?

This is an internal implementation detail. What happens is that `thread`'s constructor will first bind the functor and provided arguments using an internal binder similar to `std::bind`, and then move the resulting bound functor into the memory allocated to store it.

> (2) And why there is a t2 MOVE and t1 COPY before calling f()?

`std::thread` performs `INVOKE(DECAY_COPY(std::forward<F>(f)), DECAY_COPY(std::forward<Args>(args))...)`. `DECAY_COPY` always return an rvalue, so `std::thread` passes everything as rvalue.

`std::bind`, meanwhile, passes bound arguments as lvalues and perfectly forward things passed to its `operator()`. The net result is that the first argument of `f` is constructed from an lvalue (hence copy) while the second argument is constructed from an rvalue (hence move).

> (3) Why t1 is still copy? This is related to (2).

`std::bind` passes bound arguments as lvalues.

> (4) isn't bind & thread's internal implemenatation store object t1 & t2 which are lvalue? Why call Test & will fail? I am curious what standard says.

The second argument is passed as an rvalue, and that doesn't bind to a `Test &`.

> (5) I just want someone to confirm with me whether this is valid and there's no danger of dangling reference, even IF we store the thread t somewhere else. For example, is the following still valid?

That's fine. Destroying a `std::thread` object doesn't destroy the thread's arguments. They'll live until the thread terminates. After all, `detach()` needs to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very clear to me now. Providing rvalue arguments to std::bind and std::thread constructor, will move the arguments into internal storage. When invoking the function, std::bind will perfect-forward the internal objects to the function, std::thread will move the internal objects to the function.

Comment: Another question, isn't std::thread a little dangerous if you pass std::ref( ). Because it will pass rvalue when invoking the call, the original object will be destroyed then?

Comment: After some testing, I think if pass std::ref to thread, it will perfect forward when invoking the function call. Else, it will pass rvalue. Hope I didn't make it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @user534498 No, `bind` always pass the internal objects as lvalues. If you pass `std::ref`, then you promise that the referenced object will not be destroyed before the thread terminates. Then, when the thread's function is called, the `reference_wrapper`'s conversion operator is invoked to obtain an lvalue reference.