# How does std::bind and std::thread copy the arguments that are perfectly forwarded?

Tags: c++, multithreading, bind, perfect-forwarding

There is something I miss about std::bind and std::thread. Internally, they both forward the rvalue reference template argument (perfect forwarding). But it is known that it copies the object passed to it, instead we wrapp the lvalue references in std::ref(). If you pass a lvalue like the following:

```
template <typename T>
void fct(T&& x)
{
    f(std::forward(x));
}

...

int r{9};
fct(r);
```

In this case, r is perfectly forwarded as an lvalue.

So, where does the copy occurs, since in the source code, they always use std::forward?

I understand the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503258/what-is-the-rationale-behind-stdbind-and-stdthread-always-copying-arguments) behind the copying step, but how is it really implemented?
Also, this could help me to understand the use of std::ref in depth.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Related: [Where in the source does gcc's std::bind copy arguments into a data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614574/where-in-the-source-does-gccs-stdbind-copy-arguments-into-a-data-structure) Also see [move semantics/behaviors in std::bind and std::thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597012/move-semantics-behaviors-in-stdbind-and-stdthread)

Comment: [`std::bind`, meanwhile, passes bound arguments as lvalues and perfectly forward things passed to its `operator()`. The net result is that the first argument of `f` is constructed from an lvalue (**hence copy**) while the second argument is constructed from an rvalue (**hence move**).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29597271/12002570)

Comment: Instead of looking at bind, have a look at lambdas (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-lambdas-anonymous-functions/) and lambda captures